# Merge multiple dataframes with different columns and rows in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Assume I have 3 dataframes as follows:

2011:

| Bridge_No | Location | Area | 2011 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NY | 10 | 3 |
| 2 | FL | 20 | 4 |
| 3 | NJ | 15 | 6 |

2012:

| Bridge_No | Location | Area | 2012 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | FL | 20 | 5 |
| 3 | NJ | 15 | 3 |
| 4 | CN | 45 | 9 |

2013:

| Bridge_No | Location | Area | 2013 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | FL | 20 | 8 |
| 6 | MI | 30 | 8 |
| 4 | CN | 45 | 9 |

I need a final merged dataset as follows:

| Bridge_No | Location | Area | 2011 | 2012 | 2013 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NY | 10 | 3 | Nan | Nan |
| 2 | FL | 20 | 4 | 5 | 8 |
| 3 | NJ | 15 | 6 | 3 | NaN |
| 4 | CN | 45 | Nan | 9 | 9 |
| 6 | MI | 30 | Nan | NaN | 8 |

Comment: You can use https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html?highlight=pandas%20merge#pandas.DataFrame.merge passing in`how='outer'` and `on=['Bridge_No', 'Location', 'Area']`

Answer (score 1):

We can iterate over each DataFrame and [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) to the shared columns (the columns on which to join), then [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) on `axis=1` to get the complete DataFrame. [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) is then used to restore the RangeIndex and columns:

```
new_df = pd.concat((
    df_.set_index(['Bridge_No', 'Location', 'Area'])
    for df_ in [df2011, df2012, df2013]
), axis=1).reset_index()
```

`new_df`:

```
   Bridge_No Location  Area  2011  2012  2013
0          1       NY    10   3.0   NaN   NaN
1          2       FL    20   4.0   5.0   8.0
2          3       NJ    15   6.0   3.0   NaN
3          4       CN    45   NaN   9.0   9.0
4          6       MI    30   NaN   NaN   8.0
```

---

Setup Used:

```
import pandas as pd

df2011 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Bridge_No': [1, 2, 3], 'Location': ['NY', 'FL', 'NJ'],
    'Area': [10, 20, 15], '2011': [3, 4, 6]
})

df2012 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Bridge_No': [2, 3, 4], 'Location': ['FL', 'NJ', 'CN'],
    'Area': [20, 15, 45], '2012': [5, 3, 9]
})

df2013 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Bridge_No': [2, 6, 4], 'Location': ['FL', 'MI', 'CN'],
    'Area': [20, 30, 45], '2013': [8, 8, 9]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us do `reduce` `merge`

```
from functools import reduce
df = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['Bridge_No', 'Location', 'Area'],how='outer'), [df1,df2,df3])
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can use something like this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_2011 = pd.read_excel('2011.xlsx')
df_2012 = pd.read_excel('2012.xlsx')
df_2013 = pd.read_excel('2013.xlsx')

df_11_12 = df_2011.merge(df_2012, how='outer', on=['Bridge_No','Location','Area'])

df = df_11_12.merge(df_2013, how='outer', on=['Bridge_No','Location','Area'])
```

The output table looks like this
[image]